# Asp.net core Blazor app with google authentication getting lots of websocket errors

Tags: asp.net, websocket

We have a simple asp.net core 3.1 Blazor server-side app which we are trying to run on google app engine but are getting lots of websocket errors during initial connection:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://[url]/_blazor?id=[id]' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

Error: Failed to start the transport 'WebSockets': Error: There was an error with the transport.
```

app.yaml specifies aspnetcore runtime and flex environment. Have also tried setting session-affinity: true

The app works fine after reloading, until the connection succeeds. I know this is pretty new territory but was hoping someone might have a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to disable auto-scaling in app.yaml:

`manual_scaling:`
    `instances: 1`